# How should I configure exim4 in Debian 11 to send mail successfully?

Tags: linux, email, smtp, exim4

I tried to configure exim4 in debian 11 after referring to the following links:

https://alexander.holbreich.org/exim-mail-google/
and

https://bobcares.com/blog/exim4-smtp-authentication/

I tried `sudo dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config` but it fails with the following options

- Send mail as smarthost
- System mail name set as my hostname:`tickets.informatics.org` (only locally configured -not available on internet)
- IP-addresses to listen on for incoming SMTP connections as:
  `127.0.0.1 ; ::1 ; 192.168.2.160` where 192.168.2.160 is my local ip address
- Other destinations for which mail is accepted: set empty
- Machines to relay mail for:  `localhost; 192.168.2.0/24`
- IP address or host name of the outgoing smarthost: `smtp.gmail.com::587`
- Hide local mail name in outgoing mail? - Yes
- Visible domain name for local users: `tickets.informatics.org`
- Keep number of DNS-queries minimal (Dial-on-Demand)? No
- Keep number of DNS-queries minimal (Dial-on-Demand)? `mbox format in /var/mail/`
- Split configuration into small files? No

After completing configuration I get the error message:

```
2022-07-18 14:50:06 Exim configuration error in line 933 of /var/lib/exim4/config.autogenerated.tmp:
  authenticator name missing
Invalid new configfile /var/lib/exim4/config.autogenerated.tmp, not installing 
/var/lib/exim4/config.autogenerated.tmp to /var/lib/exim4/config.autogenerated
```

I also followed the second link and did changes as mentioned in the link.
When I run `sudo systemctl status exim4` I get the failed status message:

```
exim4.service - LSB: exim Mail Transport Agent
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/exim4; generated)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2022-07-18 10:14:49 IST; 4h 39min ago
       Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
    Process: 1367 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/exim4 start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 136ms

Jul 18 10:14:49 tickets.informatics.org systemd[1]: Starting LSB: exim Mail Transport Agent...
Jul 18 10:14:49 tickets.informatics.org exim4[1367]: Starting MTA:
Jul 18 10:14:49 tickets.informatics.org exim4[1625]: 2022-07-18 10:14:49 Exim configuration error in line 933 >
Jul 18 10:14:49 tickets.informatics.org exim4[1625]:   authenticator name missing
Jul 18 10:14:49 tickets.informatics.org exim4[1627]: Invalid new configfile /var/lib/exim4/config.autogenerate>
Jul 18 10:14:49 tickets.informatics.org exim4[1627]: /var/lib/exim4/config.autogenerated.tmp to /var/lib/exim4>
Jul 18 10:14:49 tickets.informatics.org systemd[1]: exim4.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status>
Jul 18 10:14:49 tickets.informatics.org systemd[1]: exim4.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 18 10:14:49 tickets.informatics.org systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: exim Mail Transport Agent.
```

How can I fix the error to send email using exim mail server and mail or sendmail command from my Debian 11 system. Please help

Comment: Now I have correctly configured `/etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template` I hadnt commented out the `plain_server` line . I also added `localhost:my-email:my-password` to my `/etc/exim4/passwd.client`
and run `sudo update-exim4.conf` and `sudo systemctl restart exim4` now runs successfully. But when I tried to send mail using `echo "<Mail Body" | mail -s "<Subject>" tanzeem@protonmail.com` the mail is not sent.

Comment: I checked my mail using the mail command and found that I cannot send mails to remote host due to authenticaion error. Probably this is bcz I could not enable "less secure app" in gmail as this setting is disabled now. How can I send emails from my localhost acting as smpt server instead of sending from remote gmail which cannot be authenticated.